# Not able to make a development build of Vuejs after correcting a high vulnerability of a dependancy

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I needed to use the vue-router module, so in order to be able to include it on my javascript file like this:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

I had to install it with npm with the command:

```
npm install vue-router
```

However, after the installation finished, it says that one of my dependancy contains a high vulnerability issue. It suggested me to run this command in order to solve the issue:

```
npm audit fix
```

It didn't work again. So this time it proposed me to use the command following command:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

And the warning for a high level vulnerability disappeared. However, when I try to build my project (for development) with the command:

```
npm run dev
```

The build fails and when I look into the log for more details here's what I get:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~predev: vueapp02@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: vueapp02@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\William\Documents\mabilletterie\bitbucket\excel_configuration\vueapp02\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\William\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: CWD: C:\Users\William\Documents\mabilletterie\bitbucket\excel_configuration\vueapp02
10 silly lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot' ]
11 silly lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vueapp02@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: vueapp02@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid vueapp02@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\William\Documents\mabilletterie\bitbucket\excel_configuration\vueapp02
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.14.2
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1

20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vueapp02@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vueapp02@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It could be an issue with your version of node. If you upgrade to the latest LTS version (10.15.0 as of today) it may fix the issue. You can see instructions for upgrading [here](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/#winmac)

Comment: You could also try updating npm with `npm install npm@latest -g`